# Issue with @variable when defining procedure MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This code is producing an error on @counter
The error code shows "Syntax Error: Unexpected '@counter' (at text suffix)"

I cant find a way to make it run,

Here is the code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE ValidateCC(IN ccNum char(16), OUT isValid BOOLEAN )
BEGIN
DECLARE @counter, @sum, @numb, @tmp AS INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE @result TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1;
SET isValid = ‘False’;
IF ccNum IS NULL THEN 
  SET @result = 0;
ELSEIF char_length(ccNum) < 12 THEN
  SET @result = 0;
SET @counter = char_length(ccNum);
IF ccNum NOT_REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN
  SET @result = 0;
END  IF;
WHILE @counter > 0 DO
  IF @counter > 1 THEN 
    SET @tmp = (ASCII(SUBSTR(ccNum, @counter, 1)) - 48) * 2;
    IF @tmp > 9 THEN
      SET @sum = @sum + @tmp - 9;
    ELSE
       SET @sum = @sum + @tmp;
    END IF;
    SET @number = @number + (ASCII(SUBSTR(ccNum, @counter, 1)) -48);
    SET @counter = @counter - 2; 
  END IF;
SET @sum = MOD((@sum + @number), 10);
IF @sum = 0 THEN
  SET @result =1
END IF;
END WHILE;
IF @result = 1 THEN
  SET isValid = ‘True’;
ELSE
  SET isValid = ‘False’;
END IF;
END ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In a stored procedure the right syntax to declare a variable (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-local-variable.html):

```
`DECLARE counter, sum, numb, tmp INT DEFAULT 0;`
```

Instead of `DECLARE @counter, @sum, @numb, @tmp AS INT DEFAULT 0;`... without `@`, `AS`